# How to Declare Typegoose Models instead of instantiate

Tags: typegoose

According to the docs - you need to 1) declare a class, 2) get the model for class and 3) use the model to create or retrieve data into another object ( see below )

It seems a waste of overhead to create/declare the model each time by way of a function ( getModelForClass ) .  Is it possible to declare this by way of inheriting or implementing the properties needed to create this in a module?

```
class User {
  @prop()
  public name?: string;
}
 
const UserModel = getModelForClass(User); // UserModel is a regular Mongoose Model with correct types
 
(async () => {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, dbName: "test" });
 
  const { _id: id } = await UserModel.create({ name: 'JohnDoe' } as User); 
  // an "as" assertion, to have types for all properties
  const user = await UserModel.findById(id).exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without typegoose fully reimplementing the way how schemas & models are made in mongoose